# Как реализовать List в словаре ресурсов XAML приложения UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

Вроде бы простой вопрос, но перерыл кучу документации и не нашел ни одного примера.
В приложении WPF в XAML список строк для использования его в дальнейшем в качестве источника данных для ComboBox реализуется достаточно просто.
Задаем в свойствах окна ссылки на соответствующие сборки:

```
xmlns:core="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
xmlns:col="clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=mscorlib"
```

И далее создаем список:

```
<col:ArrayList x:Key="rightsList">
    <core:String>Нет доступа</core:String>
    <core:String>Администратор</core:String>
    <core:String>Руководитель подразделения</core:String>
    <core:String>Диспетчер</core:String>
    <core:String>Директор по производству</core:String>
</col:ArrayList>
```

Вопрос, как реализовать аналогичный список в UWP? Переделать в лоб не получается, возникает ошибка XDG0062 и подсвечивается col:ArrayList:

```
xmlns:col="using:System.Collections"

<col:ArrayList x:Key="rightsList">
    <x:String>Нет доступа</x:String>
    <x:String>Администратор</x:String>
    <x:String>Руководитель подразделения</x:String>
    <x:String>Диспетчер</x:String>
    <x:String>Директор по производству</x:String>
</col:ArrayList>
```

Comment: Зачем это вам? Храните коллекцию строк в VM или в модели

Comment: @Андрей NOP Хранить в VM в данном случае неправильно, так как эта коллекция строк используется в нескольких контролах на разных страницах (MainPage и нескольких диалоговых окнах). В модели - конечно можно, но как мне кажется также концептуально неверно. Самым верным решением мне кажется использование словаря ресурсов, подключенным к App.xaml

Comment: А мне как раз кажется что это правильно, это же коллекция из предметной области, зачем View что-то знать о ней

Comment: @АндрейNOP Может вы и правы. В итоге перенес коллекцию строк в модель, все работает. Но все равно интересно было бы узнать, как реализовать список строк в XAML на UWP.

Comment: По простому — никак, нету в UWP такого функционала (как и многого другого).

Answer (score 1):

Нужно определить свою реализацию коллекции и использовать её в XAML

C#

```
public class SomeCollection : List<string>
{
}
```

Xaml

```
<Page
    x:Class="Pages.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:pages="using:Pages.MainPage"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.Resources>
        <pages:SomeCollection x:Key="SomeCollection">
            <x:String>Item 1</x:String>
            <x:String>Item 2</x:String>
            <x:String>Item 3</x:String>
            <x:String>Item 4</x:String>
            <x:String>Item 5</x:String>
        </pages:SomeCollection>

    </Page.Resources>

    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource SomeCollection}"/>
</Page>
```